# Installing Microsoft Access Database Engine prerequisite without user intervention in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am continuing with my work in Inno Setup, So now I have a new questions about it.
I am trying of to execute some programs before install my final application, for this purpose I am using [`Exec`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec) function.

When I try with the following code:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy noencryption
Source: "Database.accdb"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

[Code]

function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
Var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
   ExtractTemporaryFile('AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe');
   if Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe'), 'quit', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
   begin
      msgbox('True: {tmp}\AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe : ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);
   end
   else begin
      msgbox('False: {tmp}\AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe : ' + SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);      
   end;
end;
```

I get this error:

[image]

On the other hand, if I use the follow code:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy noencryption
Source: "Database.accdb"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

[Code]

function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
Var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
   ExtractTemporaryFile('AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe');
   if Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe'), '', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
   begin
      msgbox('True: {tmp}\AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe : ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);
   end
   else begin
      msgbox('False: {tmp}\AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe : ' + SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);      
   end;
end;
```

I get the installation wizard of the another file. Some like this:

[image]

I want to install my other programs automatically, without user intervention.

Is it possible? Can you help me?

Thank for advance!

Answer (score 1):

The usage screen says `/quiet`, and you use `quit`.

So use `/quiet`, not `quit`:

```pascal
if Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe'), '/quiet', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
```

Comment: Hi @MartinPrikryl, Keeps the first msgbox, _"Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010"_  and doesn't installs the program.

Comment: Well, we are not going to find a correct command-line arguments of a random executable for you. That's not a programming question at all. It's not even related to Inno Setup.

Answer (score 0):

I was inattentive, the correct answer is in the first picture. **The word that should be used is: /quiet**; not /quite, not /quit.

As support (if this happens again to someone other) I leave the next link:

[Description of the command-line switches that are supported by a software installation package, an update package, or a hotfix package that was created by using Microsoft Self-Extractor](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/912203)
.

Likewise many thaks for you attention.

Answer (score 0):

The option needed is :

> /passive  Runs the update without any interaction from the user.

```pascal
if Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe'), '/passive', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
```